# How to get part of model expression points to in strongly typed HtmlHelper extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

ok say i have the following model:

```
public class bar{
    public string bar {get; set; }
}

public class foo{
    public bar mybar{get; set;}
    public string anotherproperty{get; set;}
}
```

And in the UI i want to do this:

```
@Html.MyWhackyHelperFor(x=>x.bar)
```

which uses :

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyWhackyHelperFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression){
//how can i get a the actual bar object here?
}
```

how do i get at the actual part of the model being refered to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the expression into a method, then call the method:

```
TValue val = expression.Compile()(htmlhelper.ViewData.Model);
```

Comment: sweet. thanks - was   TValue val = expression.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model); to be exact ffr :)